# glLinkProgram crashes even though glCompileShader does not return any error

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es

I am trying to make the native code from https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/79/e5/OpenGL%20ES%20Tessellation.zip work on my Samsung Galaxy S5. I have disabled Tessellation in the code.

I have also changed the code to use OpenGLS ES 3.0.

The program runs and successfully compiles the attached shader but when the program calls glLinkProgram with compiled shader, glLinkProgram crashes. The program calls glError when compiling the shader and there is no error at that time.

Can someone help me how to debug this?

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Copyright 2014 Intel Corporation
// All Rights Reserved
//
// Permission is granted to use, copy, distribute and prepare derivative works of this
// software for any purpose and without fee, provided, that the above copyright notice
// and this statement appear in all copies.  Intel makes no representations about the
// suitability of this software for any purpose.  THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS."
// INTEL SPECIFICALLY DISCLAIMS ALL WARRANTIES, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, AND ALL LIABILITY,
// INCLUDING CONSEQUENTIAL AND OTHER INDIRECT DAMAGES, FOR THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE,
// INCLUDING LIABILITY FOR INFRINGEMENT OF ANY PROPRIETARY RIGHTS, AND INCLUDING THE
// WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  Intel does not
// assume any responsibility for any errors which may appear in this software nor any
// responsibility to update it.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Generated by ShaderGenerator.exe version 0.13
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Fog color in both shaders
// Skybox

const float TessellationHeight = 5500.0; // Height of a 1.0 in the height map (height map * TessellationHeight)

const int NumLights = 2;
const vec3 LightDirections[NumLights] = vec3[]( vec3(-1.0, -1.0,  -1.0),
                                                vec3(0.5, -1.0,  1.0) );
const vec3 LightColors[NumLights] = vec3[]( vec3(0.362, 0.526, 0.575),
                                            vec3(0.630, 0.914, 1.0));

// -------------------------------------
layout (std140, row_major) uniform cbPerModelValues
{
   mat4 World;
   mat4 NormalMatrix;
   mat4 WorldViewProjection;
   mat4 InverseWorld;
   mat4 LightWorldViewProjection;
   vec4 BoundingBoxCenterWorldSpace;
   vec4 BoundingBoxHalfWorldSpace;
   vec4 BoundingBoxCenterObjectSpace;
   vec4 BoundingBoxHalfObjectSpace;
};

// -------------------------------------
layout (std140, row_major) uniform cbPerFrameValues
{
   mat4  View;
   mat4  InverseView;
   mat4  Projection;
   mat4  ViewProjection;
   vec4  AmbientColor;
   vec4  LightColor;
   vec4  LightDirection;
   vec4  EyePosition;
   vec4  MaxTessellation;
};
// -------------------------------------
uniform sampler2D Texture0;
uniform sampler2D Texture1;
uniform sampler2D Texture2;
// -------------------------------------
#ifdef GLSL_VERTEX_SHADER
precision highp float;

#define POSITION  0
#define NORMAL    1
#define BINORMAL  2
#define TANGENT   3
#define COLOR   4
#define TEXCOORD0 5
// -------------------------------------
layout (location = POSITION)  in vec3 Position; // Projected position
layout (location = NORMAL)    in vec3 Normal;
layout (location = TANGENT)   in vec3 Tangent;
layout (location = BINORMAL)  in vec3 Binormal;
layout (location = TEXCOORD0) in vec2 UV0;
// -------------------------------------
out vec4 outPosition;
out vec3 outNormal;
out vec3 outTangent;
out vec3 outBinormal;
out vec2 outUV0;
out vec3 outWorldPosition; // Object space position 
#endif //GLSL_VERTEX_SHADER
#ifdef GLSL_FRAGMENT_SHADER
precision highp float;
// -------------------------------------
in vec4 outPosition;
in vec3 outNormal;
in vec3 outTangent;
in vec3 outBinormal;
in vec2 outUV0;
in vec3 outWorldPosition; // Object space position 
in vec3 outTriDistance;
// -------------------------------------
vec4 DIFFUSETMP( )
{
    return texture(Texture0,(((outUV0)) *(20.0)) );
}

// -------------------------------------
vec4 NORMAL( )
{
    return texture(Texture1,(((outUV0)) *(1.0)) ) * 2.0 - 1.0;
}

// -------------------------------------
vec4 AOMAP( )
{
    return texture(Texture2,(((outUV0)) *(1.0)) );
}

// -------------------------------------
vec4 DIFFUSE( )
{
    vec4 diffuse = DIFFUSETMP() * AOMAP();
#ifdef OPENGL_ES
    diffuse.rgb = pow(diffuse.rgb, vec3(2.2));
#endif
    return diffuse*vec4(2.0);
}

// -------------------------------------
vec4 AMBIENT( )
{
    return DIFFUSE();
}

// -------------------------------------
#endif //GLSL_FRAGMENT_SHADER

#ifdef GLSL_VERTEX_SHADER
// -------------------------------------
void main( )
{
    outPosition = vec4( Position, 1.0);
    outWorldPosition = (outPosition * World).xyz;
    outNormal   = Normal   * mat3(World);
    outTangent  = Tangent  * mat3(World);
    outBinormal = Binormal * mat3(World);
    outUV0 = UV0;
}

#endif //GLSL_VERTEX_SHADER
#ifdef  GLSL_TESS_CONTROL_SHADER

precision highp float;

#ifdef OPENGL_ES
#extension GL_INTEL_tessellation:require
#endif

layout(vertices = 3) out;

in vec4 outPosition[];
in vec3 outNormal[];
in vec3 outTangent[];
in vec3 outBinormal[];
in vec2 outUV0[];
in vec3 outWorldPosition[];

out  vec4  tcPosition[3];
out  vec3  tcNormal[3];
out  vec3  tcTangent[3];
out  vec3  tcBinormal[3];
out  vec2  tcUV0[3];
out  vec3  tcWorldPosition[3];

float level(float d)
{
    d = d/55000.0; // d = [0..1]
    float s = clamp(1.0*(d), 0.0, 1.0);
    return mix(MaxTessellation.x,1.0, s);
}
void main()
{
    tcPosition[gl_InvocationID] = outPosition[gl_InvocationID];
    tcWorldPosition[gl_InvocationID] = outWorldPosition[gl_InvocationID];

    tcNormal[gl_InvocationID] = outNormal[gl_InvocationID];
    tcBinormal[gl_InvocationID] = outBinormal[gl_InvocationID];
    tcTangent[gl_InvocationID] = outTangent[gl_InvocationID];
    tcUV0[gl_InvocationID] = outUV0[gl_InvocationID];

    if(gl_InvocationID == 0) {
        vec3 CamPos = EyePosition.xyz;

        float d0 = distance(CamPos, outWorldPosition[0]);
        float d1 = distance(CamPos, outWorldPosition[1]);
        float d2 = distance(CamPos, outWorldPosition[2]);

        gl_TessLevelOuter[2] = level(mix(d0,d1,0.5));
        gl_TessLevelOuter[0] = level(mix(d1,d2,0.5));
        gl_TessLevelOuter[1] = level(mix(d2,d0,0.5));

        float inner = max(max(gl_TessLevelOuter[0], gl_TessLevelOuter[1]),gl_TessLevelOuter[2]);
        gl_TessLevelInner[0] = inner;
    }
}

#endif  //GLSL_TESS_CONTROL_SHADER

#ifdef GLSL_TESS_EVALUATION_SHADER

precision highp float;

#ifdef OPENGL_ES
#extension GL_INTEL_tessellation:require
#endif // OPENGL_ES

layout(triangles,fractional_odd_spacing,ccw) in;

in  vec4  tcPosition[];
in  vec3  tcNormal[];
in  vec3  tcTangent[];
in  vec3  tcBinormal[];
in  vec2  tcUV0[];
in  vec3  tcWorldPosition[];

out vec4 outPosition;
out vec3 outNormal;
out vec3 outTangent;
out vec3 outBinormal;
out vec2 outUV0;
out vec3 outWorldPosition;

vec2 interpolate(vec2 a, vec2 b, vec2 c)
{
    vec2 p0 = vec2(gl_TessCoord.x) * a;
    vec2 p1 = vec2(gl_TessCoord.y) * b;
    vec2 p2 = vec2(gl_TessCoord.z) * c;
    return p0+p1+p2;
}
vec3 interpolate(vec3 a, vec3 b, vec3 c)
{
    vec3 p0 = vec3(gl_TessCoord.x) * a;
    vec3 p1 = vec3(gl_TessCoord.y) * b;
    vec3 p2 = vec3(gl_TessCoord.z) * c;
    return p0+p1+p2;
}
vec4 interpolate(vec4 a, vec4 b, vec4 c)
{
    vec4 p0 = vec4(gl_TessCoord.x) * a;
    vec4 p1 = vec4(gl_TessCoord.y) * b;
    vec4 p2 = vec4(gl_TessCoord.z) * c;
    return p0+p1+p2;
}

void main()
{
    outPosition = interpolate(tcPosition[0],tcPosition[1],tcPosition[2]);
    outUV0 = interpolate(tcUV0[0],tcUV0[1],tcUV0[2]);
    outWorldPosition = interpolate(tcWorldPosition[0],tcWorldPosition[1],tcWorldPosition[2]);
    outNormal = interpolate(tcNormal[0],tcNormal[1],tcNormal[2]);
    outTangent = interpolate(tcTangent[0],tcTangent[1],tcTangent[2]);
    outBinormal = interpolate(tcBinormal[0],tcBinormal[1],tcBinormal[2]);

    float y = texture(Texture1,(outUV0)).a * TessellationHeight;
    outPosition.y = y;

    outPosition   = outPosition * WorldViewProjection;

    gl_Position = outPosition;
}
#endif  //GLSL_TESS_EVALUATION_SHADER

#ifdef GLSL_FRAGMENT_SHADER
out vec4 fragColor;// -------------------------------------

void main( )
{
    vec4 result = vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);

    vec3 normal   = outNormal;
    vec3 tangent  = outTangent;
    vec3 binormal = outBinormal;
    mat3 tangentToWorld = mat3(tangent, binormal, normal);
    normal = normalize( tangentToWorld * NORMAL().bgr );
    float  shadowAmount = 1.0;

    // Ambient-related computation
    vec3 ambient = AmbientColor.rgb * AMBIENT().rgb;
    result.xyz +=  ambient;
    vec3 lightDirection = -LightDirection.xyz;

    // Diffuse-related computation
    vec3 albedo = DIFFUSE().rgb;

    for(int ii=0; ii<NumLights; ++ii) {
        lightDirection = -LightDirections[ii];
        float  nDotL = max( 0.0,dot( normal, lightDirection ) );
        vec3 diffuse = LightColors[ii] * nDotL * shadowAmount  * albedo;
        result.xyz += diffuse * (1.0/float(NumLights));
    }

    fragColor =  result;

    const vec4 FogColor = vec4(0.211,0.223,0.226,1.0);
    const float MinFogDistance = 5000.0;
    const float MaxFogDistance = 75000.0;
    float dist = distance(outWorldPosition, EyePosition.xyz);
    float fog_factor = clamp((MaxFogDistance - dist)/(MaxFogDistance - MinFogDistance),0.0,1.0);
    fragColor =  mix(fragColor,FogColor,1.0-fog_factor);

    #ifdef OPENGL_ES
    fragColor.rgb = pow(fragColor.rgb, vec3(0.454545454545));
    #endif
}

#endif //GLSL_FRAGMENT_SHADER
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem can come from dynamic indexing of array in a fragment Shader which is not supported by all the implementations. (see https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf p103. Note that it's OK in vertex shaders...)

In your code :

```
for(int ii=0; ii<NumLights; ++ii) {
    lightDirection = -LightDirections[ii];
    float  nDotL = max( 0.0,dot( normal, lightDirection ) );
    vec3 diffuse = LightColors[ii] * nDotL * shadowAmount  * albedo;
    result.xyz += diffuse * (1.0/float(NumLights));
}
```

Try to debug with constant indexing. Replace all xxx[ii] by xxx[0]. If it work that way, then you're probably facing this dynamic indexing limitation.

One hackish way to bypass this issue : use float for loops and create an int var in the loop body:

```
float NumLights_f = float(NumLights);
for(float ii_f=0.; ii_f<NumLights_f; ++ii_f) {
    int ii = int(ii_f);
    lightDirection = -LightDirections[ii];
    float  nDotL = max( 0.0,dot( normal, lightDirection ) );
    vec3 diffuse = LightColors[ii] * nDotL * shadowAmount  * albedo;
    result.xyz += diffuse * (1.0/float(NumLights));
}
```

For some reason, it solved my similar bug. I'm no glsl-es guru, I'm curious about WHY this work. And it may comes at the price of performance penalty... Is it because of loops unroll ? int(ii_f) is like a constant after unrolling ?