# Android opengl es linkprogram crash

Tags: android, opengl-es

In some mobile phones, this code works normally, but when I change a mobile phone, it crashes. The place of crash was in linkprogram. After I deleted part of the code in the fragment shader, it returned to normal. Is there any restriction on fragment shader that I don't know? Please check it for me. This is my code

```c
#version 300 es

struct Material {
//漫反射
    sampler2D diffuse;
//镜面光照
    sampler2D specular;
//发光
    sampler2D emission;
//镜面反光度
    float shininess;
};

struct DirLight {
//光照方向
    vec3 direction;

//环境光强度
    vec3 ambient;
//漫反射强度
    vec3 diffuse;
//镜面反射强度
    vec3 specular;
};

struct PointLight {
//光照位置
    vec3 position;

//环境光强度
    vec3 ambient;
//漫反射强度
    vec3 diffuse;
//镜面反射强度
    vec3 specular;

//光照距离的三个系数
    float constant;
    float linear;
    float quadratic;
};

//聚光
struct SpotLight{
    vec3 position;
    vec3 direction;
    float cutOff;
    float outerCutOff;

    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;

    float constant;
    float linear;
    float quadratic;
};

precision mediump float;
in vec2 TexCoords;
in vec3 Normal;
in vec3 FragPos;


//视线位置
uniform vec3 viewPos;
//材质
uniform Material material;
//平行光照
uniform DirLight dirLight;
#define NR_POINT_LIGHTS 4
uniform PointLight pointLights[NR_POINT_LIGHTS];
uniform SpotLight spotLight;

out vec4 FragColor;

//计算定向光照
vec3 CalcDirLight(DirLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 viewDir){
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(-light.direction);
    // 漫反射着色
    float diff = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
    // 镜面光着色
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);
    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), material.shininess);
    // 合并结果
    vec3 ambient  = light.ambient  * vec3(texture(material.diffuse, TexCoords));
    vec3 diffuse  = light.diffuse  * diff * vec3(texture(material.diffuse, TexCoords));
    vec3 specular = light.specular * spec * vec3(texture(material.specular, TexCoords));
    return (ambient + diffuse + specular);
}

//计算点光源光照
vec3 CalcPointLight(PointLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDir){
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(light.position - fragPos);
    // 漫反射着色
    float diff = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
    // 镜面光着色
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);
    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), material.shininess);
    // 合并结果
    vec3 ambient  = light.ambient  * vec3(texture(material.diffuse, TexCoords));
    vec3 diffuse  = light.diffuse  * diff * vec3(texture(material.diffuse, TexCoords));
    vec3 specular = light.specular * spec * vec3(texture(material.specular, TexCoords));
    //衰减
    float distance    = length(light.position - fragPos);
    float attenuation = 1.0 / (light.constant + light.linear * distance +  light.quadratic * (distance * distance));

    return (ambient  + diffuse + specular) * attenuation;
}

//计算聚光光照
vec3 CalcSpotLight(SpotLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDir)
{
    // ambient
    vec3 ambient = light.ambient * texture(material.diffuse, TexCoords).rgb;

    // diffuse
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(light.position - fragPos);
    float diff = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse * diff * texture(material.diffuse, TexCoords).rgb;

    // specular
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);
    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), material.shininess);
    vec3 specular = light.specular * spec * texture(material.specular, TexCoords).rgb;

    // spotlight (soft edges) 计算聚光（边缘模糊）
    float theta = dot(lightDir, normalize(-light.direction));//Cos,越远越小
    float epsilon = (light.cutOff - light.outerCutOff);
    float intensity = clamp((theta - light.outerCutOff) / epsilon, 0.0, 1.0);
    diffuse  *= intensity;
    specular *= intensity;

    // attenuation
    float distance    = length(light.position - fragPos);
    float attenuation = 1.0 / (light.constant + light.linear * distance + light.quadratic * (distance * distance));

    return (ambient + diffuse + specular) * attenuation;
}

void main()
{
    // 属性
    vec3 norm = normalize(Normal);
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - FragPos);

    // 第一阶段：定向光照
    vec3 result = CalcDirLight(dirLight, norm, viewDir);
    // 第二阶段：点光源
    for (int i = 0; i < NR_POINT_LIGHTS; i++)
    {
        result += CalcPointLight(pointLights[i], norm, FragPos, viewDir);
    }
//    // 第三阶段：聚光
//    result += CalcSpotLight(spotLight, norm, FragPos, viewDir);

    FragColor = vec4(result, 1.0);

}
```

This is the error log

```sh
2022-01-01 10:54:08.393 21129-21161/com.example.demo A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 21161 (GLThread 1163)
2022-01-01 10:54:08.468 21165-21165/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2022-01-01 10:54:08.468 21165-21165/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'xiaomi/ugglite/ugglite:7.1.2/N2G47H/V11.0.2.0.NDFCNXM:user/release-keys'
2022-01-01 10:54:08.468 21165-21165/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
2022-01-01 10:54:08.469 21165-21165/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
2022-01-01 10:54:08.469 21165-21165/? A/DEBUG: pid: 21129, tid: 21161, name: GLThread 1163  >>> com.example.demo <<<
2022-01-01 10:54:08.469 21165-21165/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
2022-01-01 10:54:08.469 21165-21165/? A/DEBUG:     x0   0000007f6b687798  x1   0000007f6b687114  x2   0000007f5df81c78  x3   8468299e3997dc55
2022-01-01 10:54:08.469 21165-21165/? A/DEBUG:     x4   0000007f5df81c7c  x5   0000007f5df82000  x6   0000007f5df81c6c  x7   0000007f5df81c68
2022-01-01 10:54:08.469 21165-21165/? A/DEBUG:     x8   0000000000000000  x9   0000000000000000  x10  0000000000000088  x11  0000000000000088
2022-01-01 10:54:08.469 21165-21165/? A/DEBUG:     x12  0000000000000087  x13  0000007f6bdc3000  x14  0000007f6bdc3780  x15  0000000000000000
2022-01-01 10:54:08.469 21165-21165/? A/DEBUG:     x16  0000007f6bdc43e0  x17  0000000000000080  x18  0000007f5df88000  x19  0000007f5daa5c38
2022-01-01 10:54:08.469 21165-21165/? A/DEBUG:     x20  0000000000000001  x21  0000007f5e565dd8  x22  0000000000000088  x23  0000007f6bf1d000
2022-01-01 10:54:08.469 21165-21165/? A/DEBUG:     x24  0000007f5daa5970  x25  0000007f5e565fa0  x26  0000007f5dad9430  x27  0000007f5daa5970
2022-01-01 10:54:08.469 21165-21165/? A/DEBUG:     x28  0000000000000001  x29  0000007f5e565cb0  x30  0000000000000000
2022-01-01 10:54:08.469 21165-21165/? A/DEBUG:     sp   0000007f5e565c70  pc   0000007f6b687370  pstate 0000000040000000
2022-01-01 10:54:08.946 21165-21165/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2022-01-01 10:54:08.947 21165-21165/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00000000002b4370  /system/vendor/lib64/libsc-a3xx.so
2022-01-01 10:54:08.947 21165-21165/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00000000002b5c38  /system/vendor/lib64/libsc-a3xx.so
2022-01-01 10:54:08.947 21165-21165/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00000000002c13c0  /system/vendor/lib64/libsc-a3xx.so
2022-01-01 10:54:08.947 21165-21165/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 000000000021f6bc  /system/vendor/lib64/libsc-a3xx.so
2022-01-01 10:54:08.947 21165-21165/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 00000000002497dc  /system/vendor/lib64/libsc-a3xx.so
2022-01-01 10:54:08.947 21165-21165/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 000000000024e830  /system/vendor/lib64/libsc-a3xx.so (__link_shaders+1392)
2022-01-01 10:54:08.947 21165-21165/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 00000000000b0dc4  /system/vendor/lib64/egl/libRBGLESv2_adreno.so (core_glLinkProgram+1080)
2022-01-01 10:54:08.947 21165-21165/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 000000000007f538  /system/vendor/lib64/egl/libRBGLESv2_adreno.so (glLinkProgram+32)
2022-01-01 10:54:08.947 21165-21165/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 0000000000006f54  /system/vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (glLinkProgram+28)
2022-01-01 10:54:08.947 21165-21165/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 0000000002254b14  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1a16000) (android.opengl.GLES20.glLinkProgram+128)
2022-01-01 10:54:08.947 21165-21165/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 00000000000d2a68  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+600)
2022-01-01 10:54:08.947 21165-21165/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 00000000000df4b0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+252)
2022-01-01 10:54:08.947 21165-21165/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 000000000029063c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter34ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+312)
2022-01-01 10:54:08.948 21165-21165/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 0000000000289618  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+592)
2022-01-01 10:54:08.948 21165-21165/? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 000000000055901c  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+356)
2022-01-01 10:54:08.948 21165-21165/? A/DEBUG:     #15 pc 00000000000c5314  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
2022-01-01 10:54:09.537 1471-1585/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '1ebee40 com.example.demo/com.example.demo.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Additional 2022/1/3
I changed the shader like this,and it work well again:

```c
#version 300 es

struct Material {
//漫反射
    sampler2D diffuse;
//镜面光照
    sampler2D specular;
//发光
    sampler2D emission;
//镜面反光度
    float shininess;
};

struct DirLight {
//光照方向
    vec3 direction;

//环境光强度
    vec3 ambient;
//漫反射强度
    vec3 diffuse;
//镜面反射强度
    vec3 specular;
};

struct PointLight {
//光照位置
    vec3 position;

//环境光强度
    vec3 ambient;
//漫反射强度
    vec3 diffuse;
//镜面反射强度
    vec3 specular;

//光照距离的三个系数
    float constant;
    float linear;
    float quadratic;
};

//聚光
struct SpotLight{
    vec3 position;
    vec3 direction;
    float cutOff;
    float outerCutOff;

    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;

    float constant;
    float linear;
    float quadratic;
};

precision mediump float;
in vec2 TexCoords;
in vec3 Normal;
in vec3 FragPos;


//视线位置
uniform vec3 viewPos;
//材质
uniform Material material;
//平行光照
uniform DirLight dirLight;
#define NR_POINT_LIGHTS 4
uniform PointLight pointLights[NR_POINT_LIGHTS];
uniform SpotLight spotLight;

out vec4 FragColor;



void main()
{
    // 属性
    vec3 normal = normalize(Normal);
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - FragPos);
//    vec3 materialDiff = texture(material.diffuse,TexCoords).rgb;
//    vec3 materialSpec = texture(material.specular,TexCoords).rgb;

    // 第一阶段：定向光照
    //    vec3 result = CalcDirLight(dirLight, norm, viewDir);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(-dirLight.direction);
    // 漫反射着色
    float diff = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
    // 镜面光着色
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);
    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), material.shininess);
    // 合并结果
    vec3 ambient  = dirLight.ambient  * texture(material.diffuse,TexCoords).rgb;
    vec3 diffuse  = dirLight.diffuse  * diff * texture(material.diffuse,TexCoords).rgb;
    vec3 specular = dirLight.specular * spec * texture(material.specular,TexCoords).rgb;
    vec3 result = ambient + diffuse + specular;

    // 第二阶段：点光源
    for (int i = 0; i < NR_POINT_LIGHTS; i++)
    {
        PointLight light = pointLights[i];
        vec3 lightDir = normalize(light.position - FragPos);
        // 漫反射着色
        float diff = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
        // 镜面光着色
        vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);
        float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), material.shininess);
        // 合并结果
        vec3 ambient  = light.ambient  * texture(material.diffuse,TexCoords).rgb;
        vec3 diffuse  = light.diffuse  * diff * texture(material.diffuse,TexCoords).rgb;
        vec3 specular = light.specular * spec * texture(material.specular,TexCoords).rgb;
        //衰减
        float distance    = length(light.position - FragPos);
        float attenuation = 1.0 / (light.constant + light.linear * distance +  light.quadratic * (distance * distance));

        result += (ambient  + diffuse + specular) * attenuation;
    }
        // 第三阶段：聚光
        // ambient
        ambient = spotLight.ambient * texture(material.diffuse,TexCoords).rgb;

        // diffuse
        lightDir = normalize(spotLight.position - FragPos);
        diff = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
        diffuse = spotLight.diffuse * diff * texture(material.diffuse,TexCoords).rgb;

        // specular
        reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);
        spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), material.shininess);
        specular = spotLight.specular * spec * texture(material.specular,TexCoords).rgb;

        // spotlight (soft edges) 计算聚光（边缘模糊）
        float theta = dot(lightDir, normalize(-spotLight.direction));//Cos,越远越小
        float epsilon = (spotLight.cutOff - spotLight.outerCutOff);
        float intensity = clamp((theta - spotLight.outerCutOff) / epsilon, 0.0, 1.0);
        diffuse  *= intensity;
        specular *= intensity;

        // attenuation
        float distance    = length(spotLight.position - FragPos);
        float attenuation = 1.0 / (spotLight.constant + spotLight.linear * distance + spotLight.quadratic * (distance * distance));

        result += (ambient + diffuse + specular) * attenuation;

    FragColor = vec4(result, 1.0);

}
```

Why is there a crash when I write those code into a method,It's Weird.

Comment: You can check if your shader compiled correctly. Use `glGetShaderInfoLog` API. [Here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=android.opengl.GLES20&method=glGetShaderInfoLog) are some examples on how to use this API.


Another quick way to check would be searching for 'shader' in your logcat. Depending on your device GPU, shader compile error may show up in the logcat. The part of the logcat you have shared is the call stack of the crash from CPU side, it does not tell much about what is going on in the GPU.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.I have called  `glGetShaderInfoLog`  but the carsh happened when I call `glLinkProgram` and I have no chance to call `glGetLinkInfoLog`.

Comment: I saw your update: can you tell me which method is causing the problem (CalcDirLight/CalcPointLight/CalcSpotLight)? Or all of them? The reason definitely would be some feature is not supported in the driver as you would expect. I was thinking if [dynamic indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27411947/gllinkprogram-crashes-even-though-glcompileshader-does-not-return-any-error) could be the issue, but from your update it doesn't seem so anymore.